# Why is this function undefined in Storybook when it's fine in the web app?

Tags: typescript, axios, storybook

I've hit an odd issue that I can't understand, whereby a function appears to be undefined within the context of running in Storybook, however it's fine within my application.

```
export function createRequest<T>(
    method: Method,
    url: string,
): AxiosCancelPromise<T> {

    console.log('FOOBAR');
    console.log(createAxiosRequestWithCancel);

    ...

    return createAxiosRequestWithCancel(method, url);
}
```

When I'm running in Storybook I'm hitting the following error:

> createAxiosRequestWithCancel is not a function
> at createRequest (axios.ts:88)

This might make sense to be if this were defined elsewhere and there was an issue importing. But `createAxiosRequestWithCancel` is defined within the same file...

```
const createAxiosRequestWithCancel = <T>(
    method: Method,
    url: string,
): AxiosCancelPromise<T> => { ... }
```

This works absolutetly fine within my application:

> axios.ts:84 FOOBAR
> axios.ts:85 (method, url, options = {}) => {
> const source = axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.CancelToken.source();
> const promise = axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default()(Object(_app_node_mo…

But Storybook just thinks it's undefined:

> FOOBAR
> axios.ts:85 undefined

Can anyone explain why this oddness might be happening, and also how I might fix or at least workaround the issue? I've not got to mocking requests yet, as I can't get past this hurdle at the moment.

Comment: are you using aliases? if yes, I had some issues with them too

Comment: @Jamal as in aliases for importing? Yes we are, so could be an issue - though I don't understand still why that would cause an issue within a single file :(

Comment: It's a weird act and I ended up replacing it, but refactor one of them and see if the problem will be fixed or not